# Reading and writing a std::vector into a file correctly

Tags: c++, file-io, stl, iostream, stdvector

That is the point. How to write and read binary files with std::vector inside them?

I was thinking something like:

```
//============ WRITING A VECTOR INTO A FILE ================
const int DIM = 6;
int array[DIM] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
std::vector<int> myVector(array, array + DIM);
ofstream FILE(Path, ios::out | ofstream::binary);
FILE.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myVector), sizeof(vector) * 6);
//===========================================================
```

But I don't know how to read this vector. Because I thought that the following was correctly but it isn't:

```
ifstream FILE(Path, ios::in | ifstream::binary);
FILE.read(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myVector), sizeof(vector) * 6);
```

So, how to perform the operation?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try using an `ostream_iterator`/`ostreambuf_iterator`, `istream_iterator`/`istreambuf_iterator`, and the STL `copy` methods:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

#include <fstream> // looks like we need this too (edit by π)

std::string path("/some/path/here");

const int DIM = 6;
int array[DIM] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
std::vector<int> myVector(array, array + DIM);
std::vector<int> newVector;

std::ofstream FILE(path, std::ios::out | std::ofstream::binary);
std::copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(FILE));

std::ifstream INFILE(path, std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
std::istreambuf_iterator iter(INFILE);
std::copy(iter.begin(), iter.end(), std::back_inserter(newVector));
```

Comment: What is the type parameter on that vector? Is it a vector of chars? Or of ints? If it isn't a vector of chars, how does copy write it to an output iterator of chars? Does it just downconvert every item to a single byte?

Comment: std::istreambuf_iterator iter(INFILE); doesn't work on MSVC2016?

Comment: @user1024 I've posted a full version of this program [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36506833/1460794)

Comment: I concur with user1024--VS 2013 compiler doesn't like taking the ifstream as an argument to the iterator instance.

Comment: This is absolutely dangerous. What if `array[0] = 256` ?  An `int` won't fit in a byte ofc, and `0x00` will be written instead

Answer (score 5):

Use `boost::serialization`.

If you don't want use `boost` - write size and `vector`.

```
size_t sz = myVector.size();
FILE.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&sz), sizeof(sz));
FILE.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&myVector[0]), sz * sizeof(myVector[0]));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
```

to serialize your vector. Read a tutorial here: http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#stl
`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Boost.Serialization might significantly affect both build times and the binary size. So if the TS need only to save a vector to a file, using serialization would be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Before reading `vector`, you should resize it: `yourVector.size(numberOfElementsYouRead)`.

Besides, `sizeof(vector<your_type>)` is just the size of the `vector` object internal implementation; vector element size is `sizeof(std::vector<your_type>::value_type)`.

Then read it like this:

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&myVector[0]), sizeof(vector<int>::element_type) * element_count);
```

Comment: OK, so, you think the way I choosed( FILE.read(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myVector), sizeof(vector) * 6); ) is correct?

Comment: @facunvd 1) don't cast to `const`; 2) calculate the size correctly, according to the above. Of course, the approach proposed by @Platinum Azure is much better.

Answer (score 1):

I used the fact that the data() method returns an address you can use for reading AND for writing.

// Assume outf is a writable filepointer (binary).
// write myVector.size() to file, then

```
fwrite(myVector.data(), sizeof(decltype(myVector)::value_type), myVector.size(), outf);
```

to read:

// read MyVector.size() from file as nv, inpf is read filepointer

```
MyVector.resize(nv);
fread(MyVector.data(), sizeof(decltype(MyVector)::value_type), nv, inpf);
```

clinging to old ways in file io, but please ignore that (even if it might irritate you :)).

A weakness is that endianness is unsupported in this way.