# Reading binary files and using stream iterators correctly

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors, iterator, iostream

Im trying to use this kind of iterators, but I have got errors for the following code:

```
void linearMatrix::Write_File_Matrix(const char *Path)
{
    ofstream FILE(Path, std::ios::out | std::ofstream::binary);
    FILE.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myWidth), sizeof(float));
    FILE.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myHeight), sizeof(float));
    ostreambuf_iterator<float> out_it (FILE);
    copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), out_it);
}

void linearMatrix::Read_File_Matrix(const char *Path)
{
    ifstream FILE(Path, std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);

    if(!FILE)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open the file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE.read(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myWidth), sizeof(myWidth));
    FILE.read(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myHeight), sizeof(myHeight));
    istreambuf_iterator<float> iter(FILE);
    copy(iter.begin(), iter.end(), std::back_inserter(myVector));
}
```

The problems are:

1- `ostreambuf_iterator<float> out_it (FILE);`

> error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to
>   ‘std::ostreambuf_iterator::streambuf_type* {aka
>   std::basic_streambuf >*}’
>   [-fpermissive]

2- `FILE.read(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myWidth), sizeof(myWidth));`

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::basic_istream::char_type* {aka char*}’ [-fpermissive]

3- `FILE.read(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myHeight), sizeof(myHeight));`

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to
>   ‘std::basic_istream::char_type* {aka char*}’ [-fpermissive]

4- `std::ifstream FILE(Path, std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);`

> error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to
>   ‘std::ostreambuf_iterator::streambuf_type* {aka
>   std::basic_streambuf >*}’
>   [-fpermissive]

5- copy(iter.begin(), iter.end(), std::back_inserter(myVector));

> error: ‘class std::istreambuf_iterator’ has no member named
>   ‘begin’
>
> error: ‘class std::istreambuf_iterator’ has no member named
>   ‘end’

What am I doing wrong? I'm using the nsight eclipse from CUDA, but compiling a C++ project with g++. I refer to: [Reading and writing a std::vector into a file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372531/reading-and-writing-a-stdvector-into-a-file-correctly)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void Write_File_Matrix(const char *Path)
{
    float myWidth = 0;
    float myHeight = 0;
    vector<float> v;
    v[0] = 1;
    v[1] = 2;
    v[2] = 3;
    ofstream outFILE(Path, ios::out | ofstream::binary);
    outFILE.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myWidth), sizeof(float));
    outFILE.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myHeight), sizeof(float));
    ostreambuf_iterator<float> out_it (outFILE);
    copy(V.begin(), V.end(), out_it);
}

void Read_File_Matrix(const char *Path)
{
    float myWidth = 0;
    float myHeight = 0;
    vector<float> v;

    ifstream inFILE(Path, ios::in | ifstream::binary);

    if(!inFILE)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open the file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    inFILE.read(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myWidth), sizeof(myWidth));
    inFILE.read(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myHeight), sizeof(myHeight));
    istreambuf_iterator<float> iter(inFILE);
    copy(iter.begin(), iter.end(), std::back_inserter(myVector));
}

int main() {

    Write_File_Matrix("M.dat");
    Read_File_Matrix("R.dat");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: OK. I will put the class linearMatrix header and implementation.

Comment: The [first S](http://sscce.org) stands for short. Can you reproduce the problem in a 10-line program?

Comment: Thanks for supplying short stand-alone program. It really does help.

Comment: Thank you Rob too. You gave me a good answer and advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1- ostreambuf_iterator out_it (FILE);
>
> error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘std::ostreambuf_iterator::streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf >*}’ [-fpermissive]

`std::ostreambuf_iterator` takes as template parameter the character type of the stream, NOT the type you want to convert to. Try:

```
std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> out_it(FILE);
```

Ditto for #4.

---

**EDIT**: Let's solve your big problem instead of your small ones:

Don't bother with iterators, just write the vector data out all in one go:

```
void Write_File_Matrix(const char *Path)
{
    float myWidth = 0;
    float myHeight = 0;
    vector<float> v;
    v[0] = 1;
    v[1] = 2;
    v[2] = 3;
    ofstream outFILE(Path, ios::out | ofstream::binary);
    outFILE.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myWidth), sizeof(float));
    outFILE.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&myHeight), sizeof(float));
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&v[0]), v.size()*sizeof(float));
}
```

Reading, however, still needs to be one-piece-at-a-time.

```
void Read_File_Matrix(const char *Path)
{
    float myWidth = 0;
    float myHeight = 0;
    vector<float> v;

    ifstream inFILE(Path, ios::in | ifstream::binary);

    if(!inFILE)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open the file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    inFILE.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&myWidth), sizeof(myWidth));
    inFILE.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&myHeight), sizeof(myHeight));
    float f;
    while( inFILE.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&f), sizeof(f)))
      v.push_back(f);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rob for your help. But my compilers gives me: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘std::ostreambuf_iterator<float>::streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<float, std::char_traits<float> >*}’ [-fpermissive] for the outFile.write vector :S

Comment: That may be due to my typo: try `v.size()`, not `v.size`.

Comment: Rob I tried with read but the compiler gave me errors and they are the same as above

Comment: Rob i changed it:inFILE.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&myWidth), sizeof(float));inFILE.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&myHeight), sizeof(float)); Now Im trying to solve the while() sentence

Comment: you can resize vector to intended size and then read all information right into vector.data()

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: removed incorrect answer to 1, 4.

Re: 2, 3. You can't read into a `const char*`; it's **const**. Cast to a `char*` instead. That's what the error message says.

Re: 5. Yes, iterators don't have `begin()` and `end()` member functions. You've already got an iterator to the beginning of the file (once the previous problems are solved). Its name is `iter`. Now you need an end-of-file iterator, and the correct call is `std::copy(iter, end_iter, std::back_inserter(myVector));`.

Comment: Re: 1,4: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator/ostreambuf_iterator , #2. The constructor **does** take a `stream` object. The problem is the template type.