# How to read from a binary file to an int32_t vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, binaryfiles

I am making a small test seeing if it is feasible to rewrite a very old binary read/write library we use internally. In the code they read a block of memory into a char array and then convert the pointer to an `int32_t` pointer to access it as an int32_t array.

**Question:** Is there a way to directly read the int32_t data into a int32_t-vector?

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream is("filename", ifstream::binary);
    if (is) 
    {       
        std::vector<int32_t> myVec(12);  //let's assume that this is indeed the correct size

        //read from is to myVec ?
    }
}
```

Comment: `is.read(&myVec[0], 12*sizeof(int32_t));` Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "the int32_t data"? An int32_t is a C++ type, not a binary data format.

Comment: You have to know that the byte order of the data written is the same as what you are reading.

Comment: I just saw that this question appeared earlier, don't know why I didn't see it before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506297/reading-and-writing-a-stdvector-into-a-file-correctly-with-iterators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` can be used:

```
is.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>(&myVec[0]), myVec.size() * sizeof(int32_t));
```

Of course this assumes that the binary data has correct endian-ness, which appears to be the case based on the background information in the question.