# How to read and write an AES key to and from a file?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, file-io, crypto++

I am trying to write an AES key to a file then read it later. I'm using the Crypto++ library, and the AES key is initialized as follows. Below, `byte` is a typedef of `unsigned char`.

```
byte key[CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH]
```

The key is 32 bytes long. I try to write it into a file with this:

```
FILE* file = fopen("C:\\key", "wb");
fwrite(key, 1, sizeof(key), file);
fclose(file);
```

And recover it using:

```
FILE* read_file = fopen("C:\\key", "rb");
fseek(read_file, 0, SEEK_END);
long int size = ftell(read_file);
fclose(read_file);

read_file = fopen("C:\\key", "rb");
unsigned char * in = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
byte readed_key = fread(in, sizeof(unsigned char), size, read_file);
fclose(read_file);
if (key == readed_key)
{
    cout << "this is the right key !";
}
free(in);
```

However, I get an error message:

> incompatible operand types : byte* and byte.

I don't understand why, since `readed_key` and `key` are initialized with `byte` and not `byte*`.

---

I looked at [AES](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) on the Crypto++ wiki, and the key is generated as follow. I figured out that I was just creating the key (not generating it):

```
SecByteBlock key(0x00, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
rnd.GenerateBlock( key, key.size() );
```

With that I can't use

```
std::vector<byte> key(32);
rnd.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
```

Because `rnd.Generateblock` can't convert `std::vector< byte > into byte*`

This is driving me crazy....

Comment: You should probably avoid `FILE*`; and stick to C++ and use an `ifstream`. Or, use a Crypto++ [`FileSource`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSource). Also see [std::byte](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Std::byte) on the Crypto++ wiki and [Issue 442, Test C++17 byte change with dry runs from various projects](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/442) in the issue tracker. `byte` is getting ready to change to `CryptoPP::byte`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a binary file into a vector of unsigned chars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15138353), [Loading a file into a vector<char>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7241871), [Efficient way of reading a file into an std::vector<char>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4761529/608639), [Reading and writing a std::vector into a file correctly with iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36506297), [Reading and writing a std::vector into a file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12372531), [How to read a file into vector in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15138785), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to read and write an AES key to and from a file?

I'm going to avoid your code since its mostly C code. Andrew pointed out some of the problems with it, so there's no sense in rehashing it. Instead I'll show you the Crypto++ and C++ way of doing things. I'll also discuss `SecByteBlock` a little.

---

Here's the Crypto++ way to read the data into a byte array using sources and sinks. You can read more about them at [Pipelines](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) in the Crypto++ wiki.

```
byte key[CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
FileSource fs("C:\\key.bin", true, new ArraySink(key, sizeof(key)));
```

Here's the Crypto++ way to write data to a file using sources and sinks.

```
byte key[CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
ArraySource as(key, sizeof(key), true, new FileSink("C:\\key.bin"));
```

---

Here's the C++ way to read the data into a byte array using streams. Its taken from [Reading and writing binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5420317/608639)

```
byte key[CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
std::ifstream fs("C:\\key.bin", std::ios::binary);
fs.read(key, sizeof(key));
```

Here's the C++ way to write data to a file using streams.

```
byte key[CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
std::ofstream fs("C:\\key.bin", std::ios::binary);
fs.write(key, sizeof(key));
```

---

> ```
> std::vector<byte> key(32);
> rnd.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
> ```
>
> Because rnd.Generateblock can't convert `std::vector< byte >` into
>   `byte*`. This is driving me crazy....

Here, you need a non-const pointer to the first element. Take the address of the first element in your vector. The same would apply to a `std::string`.

```
std::vector<byte> key(32);
rnd.GenerateBlock(&key[0], key.size());
```

---

Since the key is sensitive, you should use a `SecByteBlock`. It zeroizes the key from memory once you are done using it.

Generally speaking, if the information is sensitive, then you want to use a `SecBlock<T>`. In the case of `SecByteBlock`, `T` is a `byte` and there's a typedef for `SecByteBlock`. But you can make a `SecBlock<T>` out of anything.

Here's the Crypto++ way to read the data into a `SecByteBlock` using sources and sinks.

```
SecByteBlock key(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
FileSource fs("C:\\key.bin", true, new ArraySink(key.begin(), key.size()));
```

---

`SecByteBlock` *can* initialize elements to a known value upon construction. You are using the feature below. All elements are initialized to `0x00`.

```
SecByteBlock key(0x00, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
rnd.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
```

Since you are overwriting the elements immediately with random data, you *should* forgo initialization. Just ask for an uninitialized block of memory:

```
SecByteBlock key(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
rnd.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, jww, Please correct `intialize` if you may. :)

Comment: Thanks @Teo. Yeah, I am an awful speller at times. If I turn on spell check, then it turns my bad spelling into bad grammar...

Comment: Hehe, that's all right. I happen to be a lousy speller myself.

Answer (score 2):

`key` is an *array* of `byte`, i.e. its type is `byte[32]` (assuming that `CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH` is an integer constant equal to 32). `byte[N]` decays to `byte*` in certain contexts, including during comparisons using `==` such as in your `if (key == readed_key)` line.

`readed_key` is defined to be `byte`, which is not the same.

Also, you're using [`fread (3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) incorrectly; the return value is the number of items read, not the data that was read. The data you read is stored in the `in` array. You need to compare each element of `key` against each element of `in`, to check that the keys are the same.

*Edit:* Thanks to [@vasek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611117/vasek) for pointing out that the comparison should be written

```
if (memcmp(key, in, size) == 0) { /* keys are equal */ }
```

---

Since you're using C++ (The Crypto++ library is a C++ library), you could use higher-level abstractions to avoid manual memory management with `malloc`/`free` and make the code easier to work with:

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ebc1a553b68e709):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using byte = char;

int main() {
    std::vector<byte> key(32);
    // Code would go here to generate the `key`
    // ...

    {
        std::ofstream out("C:\\key", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        out.write(key.data(), key.size());
    } // file is closed automatically here!

    std::vector<byte> read_key(32);
    {
        std::ifstream in("C:\\key", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        in.read(read_key.data(), read_key.size());
    }

    if (key == read_key) {
        std::cout << "Keys are equal!\n";
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Here, the `std::vector<byte>` handles the memory allocation (you just tell it the size in the constructor; use `.data()` to get a pointer to the contents; comparison of the full key comes for free with `std::vector`'s `operator==`), and the C++ iostreams `read`/`write` is a little easier to follow compared to `fread`/`fwrite`. You can still do the seek to determine the key size; I'll leave that as an [exercise to the reader](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).

Comment: Also worth noting comparation should be done using `if (memcmp(key, in, size) == 0) { /* keys are equal */ }`

Comment: I understand.So is there a way (with fread or not) to return the data in the file and store it in a byte array ?

Comment: `fread(in, sizeof(unsigned char), size, read_file)` is correct, but key is not in `fread`'s return value, but in `in` array.

Comment: ok."in" is an unsigned char*,so i don't want to store the readed key in it.Could i put a byte variable instead of "in" in the fread ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Give it a try.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning... `if (memcmp(key, in, size) == 0)` is not constant time. If OP needs a constant time comparison to avoid leaking information, then he/she should use [`VerifyBufsEqual`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/VerifyBufsEqual). But I'm guessing he needs something different to avoid the oracle... He/Shee should be using an [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) mode of operation; or maybe, a Key Confirmation operation.

Comment: @jww yes. I'd go so far as to say, unless this is a personal project to learn how AES works, the OP shouldn't be implementing crypto at all; it's very hard to do right, even with a library like Crypto++, because the code that uses it must also be aware of how to avoid leaking or weaknesses.