# Save & read double vector from file C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, ifstream

I'm trying to save a `std::vector<double>` to a file and read to rebuild the `std::vector<double>`. This code from rex ([original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36506833/4112088)) works for `std::vector<char>` but not for doubles. Once I tried to modify this to work with doubles, numbers lose decimal points. Here is my attempt (modified code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::string filename("savefile");

std::vector<double> myVector{1321.32132,16.32131,32.321,64,3213.454};

void write_vector_to_file(const std::vector<double>& myVector, std::string filename);
std::vector<double> read_vector_from_file(std::string filename);

int main()
{
    write_vector_to_file(myVector, filename);
    auto newVector{read_vector_from_file(filename)};
    //printing output
    std::cout << newVector.at(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void write_vector_to_file(const std::vector<double>& myVector,std::string filename)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(filename,std::ios::out | std::ofstream::binary);
    std::ostream_iterator<char> osi{ofs};
    std::copy(myVector.begin(),myVector.end(),osi);
}

std::vector<double> read_vector_from_file(std::string filename)
{
    std::vector<double> newVector{};
    std::ifstream ifs(filename,std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iter(ifs);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end{};
    std::copy(iter,end,std::back_inserter(newVector));
    return newVector;
}
```

This code outputs `16` instead of `16.32131`.
What should I do to make this work with doubles?
Thank you.

Comment: You should post the code you already modified, explain what it does wrong and then we can help.

Comment: sorry @SamiKuhmonen , I updated the post

Comment: You could make a better [mcve] if you stream to and from a `std::strstream` instead of writing files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
void write_vector_to_file(const std::vector<double>& myVector, std::string filename)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::out | std::ofstream::binary);
    std::ostream_iterator<char> osi{ ofs };
    const char* beginByte = (char*)&myVector[0];

    const char* endByte = (char*)&myVector.back() + sizeof(double);
    std::copy(beginByte, endByte, osi);
}

std::vector<double> read_vector_from_file(std::string filename)
{
    std::vector<char> buffer{};
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iter(ifs);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end{};
    std::copy(iter, end, std::back_inserter(buffer));
    std::vector<double> newVector(buffer.size() / sizeof(double));
    memcpy(&newVector[0], &buffer[0], buffer.size());
    return newVector;
}
```

The problem was that doubles where being cast to char before storing.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but doing so brings out this error
`error: no matching function for call to ‘std::istreambuf_iterator<double>::istreambuf_iterator(std::ifstream&)’`

Comment: You need the `ostream_iterator` to have a delimiter string (whitespace), and the `istreambuf_iterator` will need to become a `istream_iterator`.  This will *still* not produce bit-wise identical values (for some double values), but it will be a lot closer, and it may be good enough.