# c++ program crashing after reading a file the second time

Tags: c++, file, class, destructor

Basically, the problem is already described in the title: When starting the program first time ( meaning that the new file is created then ), it works perfectly and it doesn't crash, but when trying a second time ( meaning that the file already is there ), it crashes.

Question is: Why does it crash and how do I prevent that from happening?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class TStudent
{
public:
    string Name, Surname;
    int Age;

    TStudent(string name, string surname, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Age = age;
        cout <<"\n";
    }

    string toString() const
    {
        return Name + " ; " + Surname + " ; " + to_string(Age);
    }

    int aux1 = sizeof(Name), aux2 = sizeof(Surname);
};


class TRegistru
{
public:
    string name, surname;
    int age;
    vector <TStudent> students;

    TRegistru(const TStudent &other)
    {
        this->name = other.Name;
        this->surname = other.Surname;
        this->age = other.Age;

        students.push_back(other);

    }

    void adauga(const TStudent& student)
    {
        students.push_back(student);
    }

    void salveaza(string file_name)// creating the file and storing the data
    {
        ofstream file1;
        file1.open(file_name, ios::app);
        file1.write((char*)&students, sizeof(students));
        file1.close();
        cout<<"\nFile saved and closed successfully.\n"<<endl;
    }

    void sterge()
    {
        students.clear();
    }

    void incarca(string file_name)// opening the file and reading the data
    {
        ifstream file2;
        file2.open(file_name, ios::in);
        if(!file2)
        {
            cout<<"Error in opening file..";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"File opened successfully.\n"<<endl;
        }
        file2.seekg(0);
        file2.read((char*)&students, sizeof(students));
    }

    void afiseaza()//printing the data
    {
        for(auto student : students)
        {
            cout << student.Name << endl ;
            cout << student.Surname << endl;
            cout << student.Age << endl;
            cout <<"\n";
        }
    }

    string toString() const
    {
        string ret{};
        for(const auto& student : students)
        {
            ret += student.toString() + "\n";
        }
        return ret;
    }


};

int main()
{
    TStudent student1("Simion", "Neculae", 21);
    TStudent student2("Elena", "Oprea", 21);
    TRegistru registru(student1);
    registru.adauga(student2);
    registru.salveaza("data.bin");// creating the file and storing the data
    registru.sterge();
    registru.incarca("data.bin");// opening the file and reading the data
    registru.afiseaza();//printing the data

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the message when it is crashing?

Comment: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372531/reading-and-writing-a-stdvector-into-a-file-correctly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write std::string to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388041/how-to-write-stdstring-to-file)

Comment: `file1.write((char*)&students, sizeof(students));` -- This could never work.  The last parameter `sizeof(students)` indicate why this could never work.  If you had 1 student, 10 students, or a million students, `sizeof(students)` would remain the same, small value.  That is because `sizeof` is a *compile-time* value -- it has no idea at runtime how many students there will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a second time your code I realised that the way you try to read and write a vector was plain wrong:

```
vector <TStudent> students;
...
    ifstream file2;
    file2.open(file_name, ios::in);
    file2.seekg(0);
    file2.read((char*)&students, sizeof(students)); // WRONG!!!
```

A vector does store its data in a contiguous way, but the address of the vector is **not** the address of the data. The correct way is to serialize each element of the vector to the file and then deserialize each element and push that into the vector.